# MySQL, PHP: Get the last 10 rows of a table dynamically after clicking a Button

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I made a Randompicker where 10 users are selected randomly and added to a database table called "winners". Every time I click on my button 10 winners are getting selected and added to the table. I'm able to get the last 10 winners with a simple sql query.

```
SELECT * from winners order by id desc limit 10;
```

I use Ajax and print out the 10 rows as a table.
The next step would be adding a "Previous" and "Next" button. If I click on the "Previous" Button I need to get the "second latest" 10 winners. What kind of a query would be needed? The button will be clickable until the oldest 10 winners are getting shown.

The winners table structure looks like this:

```
NR USERID USERNAME DATE
```

I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: It is a pagination problem. With every Next/Previous button, you specify a page number and limit to get next records using LIMIT

Comment: Got it. I just needed the specific name of the problem. Now I will be able to read about it!

Comment: MySQL SELECT supports an OFFSET in the LIMIT clause. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html.